# Select all users who wrote a minimum amount of messages in a fixed time frame

Tags: sql

Table **user_message**:

```
+----+---------+-------+------------+
| id | from_id | to_id | time_stamp |
+----+---------+-------+------------+
|  1 |    1    |   2   | 1414700000 |
|  2 |    2    |   1   | 1414700100 |
|  3 |    3    |   1   | 1414701000 |
|  4 |    3    |   2   | 1414701001 |
|  5 |    3    |   4   | 1414701002 |
|  6 |    1    |   3   | 1414701100 |
+----+---------+-------+------------+
```

I am now trying to get all users who wrote a minimum amount of messages, let's say 3, to other users in a fixed time frame, let's say 5 seconds. As in this example, I'd like to get a result looking similar to this:

```
+----+----+-------+
| from_id | count |
+---------+-------+
|    3    |   3   |
+---------+-------+
```

The idea of this is to check the messages for spam. A nice bonus would be to only take messages into account that share the same content.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL, but I chose not to specify a DBMS as, in my eyes, a DBMS-independent solution may be more useful to reach more users (if by any time someone should be looking for a similar solution).

Comment: When you talk about date / timestamp field there aren't general solution ;(

Answer (score 2):

The following uses a `join` for this purpose:

```
select um.*, count(*) as cnt
from user_message um join
     user_message um2
     on um.from_id = um2.from_id and
        um2.time_stamp between um.time_stamp and um.time_stamp + 3
group by um.id
having count(*) >= 3;
```

For performance, you would want an index on `user_message(from_id, time_stamp)`.  Even with the index, if you have a large-ish table, the performance might not be so great.

EDIT:

Actually, another way to write this that might be more efficient is:

```
select um.*,
       (select count(*)
        from user_message um2
        where um.from_id = um2.from_id and
              um2.time_stamp between um.time_stamp and um.time_stamp + 3
       ) as cnt
from user_message um
having cnt >= 3;
```

This uses a MySQL extension that allows `having` in a non-aggregation query.

Comment: can you explain why chose to group by "um.id"?

Comment: @RobsonFilhoColodeti . . . You cannot `group by um.*`.  I could list all the columns, but both MySQL and the ANSI standard allow grouping by a unique identifier (although most databases do not support it).

Comment: sure you cannot group by um.*, but i was thinking that um.from_id was more correct, am I wrong? I'm asking you because you seem to have a lot of experience in SQL =)

Comment: @RobsonFilhoColodeti . . . That is a bit more complicated to explain.  If you group by `um.from_id` then you will be counting the number of messages within X seconds of all messages (for a `from_id`).  The `group by id` fixes the time frame to each message.

Answer (score 1):

For every message (u1) find all messages (u2) sent from the same user in this second or the four previous seconds. Keep those u1 that have at least 3 u2. At last group by from_id to show one record per from_id with the maximum number of sent messages.

```
select from_id, max(cnt) as max_count
from
(
  select u1.id, u1.from_id, count(*) as cnt
  from user_message u1
  join user_message u2 
    on u2.from_id = u1.from_id 
    -- and u2.content = u1.content
    and u2.time_stamp between u1.time_stamp - 4 and u1.time_stamp
  group by u1.id, u1.from_id
  having count(*) >= 3
) as init
group by from_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for adding a derived table name @Icefyre. This is indeed necessary in some dbms, in others it is not. Also the AS is valid in some dbms and not in others. As you mention in your comments section that you are using MySQL the correction applied by you is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it seems to work great (even though it's pretty slow - but that wasn't a requirement). I know about the optional `as`, however there's a minimum amount of characters you need to change to edit a post, so that was a quick workaround. :)

Comment: Yes this is slow. This is because we take every message and count adjacent messages. This is much work. It would be faster not to show the maximum count per user, but only see if *at least* one series of 3 adjacent exist and then stop searching further for that user. This however is quite complicated in SQL and most likely to be solved with LAG which MySQL doesn't support. (Or with a programming language like PL/SQL in Oracle dbms.)

Comment: To get my query faster, we would have to reduce the intermediate result, i.e. have less u1/u2 matches, i.e. additionally compare content. As comparing message contents will be slow, however, we may not win anything. So a solution might be to add a column and fill it with a hash code for the content. With an index on that hash code, comparision would be fast. And with the additional comparision there would be much fewer matches and thus less data to process.